# Sveltekit updating database is not updating on server

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I've managed to update the boolean value from false to true when a newly registered user submits a welcome form. When the form is submitted, the user should be redirected to his dashboard.

When I submit the form, I can see that the bpp;ean is updated in mySQLWorkbench, but not on the server because it won't redirect me, and after a pagerefresh, the fetched user from the database still returns a false for the boolean variable, while it should be true.

Am I overlooking something?

```
import { auth } from "$lib/server/lucia";
import type { PageServerLoad,Actions } from './$types.js';
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";


export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
    session = await locals.auth.validate();
     user = await auth.getUser(session.user.userId)
     if (session && user.wizard == true) 
          throw redirect(302, "/");
    return {};
};

let session;
let user


export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request, locals }) => {
          const formData = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData())
          try {
               user = await auth.updateUserAttributes(session.user.userId, {
                    wizard: true
               });
          } catch (e) {
               console.log(e)
          }
          throw redirect(302, '/dashboard');
    }
};
```

[image: Example]

Comment: in which file is this done ?

Comment: +page.server.ts